# Can we eat foods just tasted by crows?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, punishment, najis

A crow has taken a fish from the pot of fishes with gravy(liquid) and flew away. In this case can I eat the rest food? 
Is it made najis or is it become Haram ?
By the way, I don't know whether that crow usually eat halal foods . 
If it has become a prohibited food and if I've eaten it , 
what's the punishment for my sin and how can I over come that sin?

Comment: I think the last question should be asked seperately.